# How to select dummy column in peewee?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

how to do

`select 'blah' as dummycolumn`

in peewee??

I have tried

`MyTable.select('blah')`

but it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyModel.select(
    MyModel.some_field.alias('another_name'),
    Value('a string literal').alias('a_string'),
    Value(12345).alias('a_number'))
```